# In Ruby, can I limit the amount of drilling down a object does when displaying itself in irb or when using .inspect?

Tags: ruby, irb, inspect

I'm writing a class for solving sudoku puzzles that has some two dimensional arrays which contain pointers to `Cells` that point back to these two dimensional arrays. Something like this:

```
def class Sudoku
  attr :rows, :columns, :blocks

  def initialize
    # build each of the rows, columns, and blocks with a 9x9 map of Cells
  end
end

def class Cell
  attr :value, :row, :column, :block

  def initialize(row, column, block, value)
    # set each pointer to its parent row, column and block etc
  end
end
```

The problem is that when I do something like:

```
p = Puzzle.new
```

in `irb`, irb freezes up. I've modified some of the code now so it doesn't do that but now if I do:

```
irb> p.rows
=> TONS OF SHIT GETS RETURNED
```

it outputs tons and tons of nested pointers and takes about 20 seconds to return to the `irb` prompt. A lot of this has to do with some infinite pointers i.e.:

```
p.rows[0][0].row[0].row[0].row[0]....
```

So I'm wondering if there is a way for Ruby to just return a shallow representation of this array since all of its pointers end up pointing back to itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redefine inspect in Puzzle and display only what you want.

For example:

```
def inspect
  "Puzzle with size #{rows.size}"
end
```

Comment: Note: `Puzzle#inspect` will be invoked when you do `p puzzleObject` or `puts puzzleObject.inspect`.

Comment: This works! @Nakilon, that is a good thing to note, but this solves my problem because `p.rows.inspect` calls up `Puzzle#inspect`. It should be noted that `p.rows` is of type `Array` so monkey patching the `Array` class with an `inspect` method might also solve my problem.